# Calling a php file via Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, joomla

I currently have this code below working A-OK, it basically loads up a pretty notification box with a message on a onClick event, so when a user presses the button then the notification pops :

```
<button id="buttonsuccess" class="btn btn-success" onClick="FunctionSuccess()">button</button>

<script>
function FunctionSuccess(){
Lobibox.notify('success', {
iconSource: 'fontAwesome',
size: 'mini',
delay: 8000,
sound: false,
title: 'Success!',
msg: 'Success message here.'
});
}
</script>
```

However, I would like to run a PHP file on the onClick event. My code to run the PHP file within the Javascript code is as follows:

```
<button id="buttonsuccess" class="btn btn-success" onClick="FunctionSuccess()">button</button>

    <script>
    function FunctionSuccess(){

$.ajax({
    url: '/copy/test.php'
})

Lobibox.notify('success', {
iconSource: 'fontAwesome',
size: 'mini',
delay: 8000,
sound: false,
title: 'Success!',
msg: 'Success message here.'
});
}
</script>
```

But this doesn't work. I actually get the notification box message as I did before, but the PHP code does not run. Instead, I get the following error on console:

```
GET http://domain.com/copy/test.php 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

I just need to execute the code within the test.php file, I don't need to get data from it or post data to it, just execute the PHP file. BTW, I've tested the PHP file, it works fine.

error_log shows no errors, no PHP errors either. The permissions on the php file is also OK.

Much appreciate any insight you may be able to provide.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

(Assuming you're using chrome..)

Check your console, and enable 'LogXMLHTTPRequests' if it isn't checked.

When you click the button, you should see the url being called in the console. Right click on that, and open in a new window.

Chances are, the wrong domain is coming up, or there's an error in the php code.

You can also open the console and select the network tab. If you have a request that generated a 500, it'll appear red, you can right click on that line, select 'copy response' and paste that into your favorite text editor.

Comment: I enabled 'LogXMLHTTPRequests' and the console shows:  XHR finished loading: GET "http://domain.com/copy/test.php". 

This is showing the correct domain and file path.
There can't be an error in the PHP code, when I run the exact same error outside of the FunctionSuccess function it works OK. It's only when running the PHP code via an ajax call inside the FunctionSuccess function is when I get the internal server 500 error.

Comment: And no HTTP 500? That sounds like a success, no?

Comment: I still get the HTTP 500 error. Sorry I should have mentioned that.

Comment: Ahh.. so mouse over the line in the console, right click, and choose 'open in new window'. Depending on the server / framework / app that you have installed, you *may* get a better idea of the error.

Comment: I have Joomla.

Opening in a new tab gives me the following:

    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set('error_log', '/error_log');
    ini_set('log_errors_max_len', 0);
    ini_set('log_errors', true);

I had those 4 lines before and above the <?php ..?> just to see if the PHP throws any errors. I don't see anything but those 4 lines.

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry I could not put this in a comment.
Please try to put url in double quote.

Comment: I get:       GET http://domain.com/copy/test.php 500 (Internal Server Error)
  XHR finished loading:     GET "http://domain.com/copy/test.php".

Comment: Ah, you forgot to put the semi-colon!

Comment: $.ajax({
    url: '/copy/test.php'
});   <---- Even with the semi colon I get the same HTTP 500 error, unless you mean the same colon elsewhere?

Comment: $.post("/copy/test.php");

Comment: POST http://domain.com/copy/test.php 500 (Internal Server Error) XHR finished loading: POST "http://domain.com/copy/test.php". <-- same error with the updates code.

Comment: please try to put (domain.com/copy/test.php) on browser and see what happen. I do not think it is code problem.